# Spring reactive - event on receiveing new message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a chat application with spring reactive webflux. When a new message is created, all subscribers get that message(this is just an example for simplify my problem). Everything is right and worked perfectly. But, now I need  **an event for subscribers when a new message arrived.**

This is my code:

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("ptpReplayProcessor")
private ReplayProcessor<String> ptpReplayProcessor;

@GetMapping(value = "/chat/subscribe", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> subscribe() {
    return Flux.from(ptpReplayProcessor);
}
```

**ReplayProcessorConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class ReplayProcessorConfig {
    @Bean("ptpReplayProcessor")
    ReplayProcessor<String> ptpReplayProcessor() {
        ReplayProcessor<String> replayProcessor = ReplayProcessor.create(0, false);
        replayProcessor.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(String ptp) {
                System.out.println("replay processor called!");
            }

        });
        return replayProcessor;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When a new message created, I call `ptpReplayProcessor.onNext(message)`. This works correctly and all clients receive message, but phrase `replay processor called!` just print from sender of message. I want to raise an event for all clients when receiving a new message. Also I tried `ReplayProcessor.doOnNext()` and `ReplayProcessor.doOnEach()` methods, but not worked. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"I want to raise an event for all clients"_?

Comment: I need to do something for clients in the backend(suppose do some checking or for logging), when a new message arrived.

Comment: They already receive the message. Why do you need an additional event?

Comment: The clients receive messages in **client side**, but I want an event in server side.

Comment: So if you have 5 clients you want 5 events to be raised on the server side for each message?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this on your subscribe method:

```
return Flux.from(ptpReplayProcessor).doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("new message has been sent"));
```

Comment: `doOnNext` is just for sender of message, not receivers. I pointed in my question that this event did not work.

Comment: In your scenario you were adding onNext event on the replay processor. thus the event was triggered only when replay processor was getting a message to send. in my case I have added onNext event on the flux which is responsible to send messages to the concrete user, so this will be triggered for every message per user. so you can effectively say that client got a message.

if you want to be sure that the message was delivered correctly there is no way to solve this only on server side. some kind of acknowledgement is mandatory on the client side too.